# How to load response data using axios in react?

Tags: reactjs, axios

How to  load response data using axios in react?

my componentdidmount:

```
var params = new URLSearchParams();
params.append('id', this.state.ids);

axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/items/select/', params)
  .then(function(response, data){

    x => {

    let push = response.data.map((idb, index)=>{
        return(

          <SingleProduct takeid={idb} />    

            )
        })
    this.setState({dataSelection: push});
    }
  })
```

i want to create map response.data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few things you need to take care of

**First:** `bind` the `axios callback` method, so that `this` inside it refers to the React component context

**Second:** Save the response in state rather than the component map

**Third:**  Map over the state in render

```
state = {
    dataSelection: []
}
componentDidMount() {
  var params = new URLSearchParams();
  params.append('id', this.state.ids);

  axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/items/select/', params)
    .then((response, data) => {
        this.setState({dataSelection: response.data});
      }
    })
}

render () {
   return (
      <div>
        {this.state.dataSelection.map((idb, index)=>{
          return(
               <SingleProduct takeid={idb} />    
            )
          })
        }
      </div>
   )
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the error: It should be `this.state.dataSelection.map` instead of `this.state.dataSelection.data.map`

Comment: Did you initialise state dataSelection to empty array